# Requirement regarding saving a text data in database(SQL)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox in which user enters text and can change the **text color**, **font bold** or **italic** of the same text.

I have to save the same format of the text that user has entered whether it is bold or green color in the database and fetch the same entered text from database and  show the data in another textbox.

How can I start with the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax HTML Editor to input the Data in Database field should be NVARCHAR(MAX). After saving the data use textarea control to show that html data.